# Bootstrap Jumbotron is not adjusting to top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

My jumbotron is not working as intended. This is my code:

```
  <div class="jumbotron fill-jumbotron">
        <div class="container" id="outer">
            <h1 align="center" id="mapsHead">Google Maps Filter</h1>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my css:

```
    .fill-jumbotron{
    height:100%;
    background: url('../assets/images/city2.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    }
```

I've tried forcing body to 100%, margins to 0 and padding:0!important; . Div #map contains a google map loaded from api. According to this bootply, my jumbotron should be working correctly but it is not:

http://www.bootply.com/MlRhkzU5GR

My viewport initial-scale is set to 1 and I've tried loading my webpage from different browsers. Chrome developer shows that in top of the jumbotron there is a blank space outside the jumbotron (body).

EDIT:

Solved issue by updating bootstrap libraries.

Comment: Can you show a fiddle of how it looks for you as opposed to the bootply?

Comment: Do you mean simulating the error?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/efcbhcv0/ Something like this, I had to force the margin:top in the css to simulate the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `top`  to `0` in your CSS the div should adhere to the top.

Comment: I forced it to show you the error, I don't have that margin-top in my real css.

Comment: Updated answer the HTML code you posted for the jumbotron is the only thing you have on the page thus far?